# MySQL LEFT JOIN duplicates results

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have a problem with implementing a module where one `project` can belong to multiple `categories`. Example: project "PHP Programmer" belongs to categories: Programming, PHP.

Assuming the following query (*select projects that belong to categories 1,3,11*):

```
SELECT projects.* FROM projects 
    LEFT JOIN pojects_category on projects.id = pojects_category.project_id 
    WHERE pojects_category.category_id IN (1,3,11) and projects.id='94'`
```

I get a the **same project returned twice**, because there are **2** matches in the `project_category` table for the `project_id` = `94`

Table `projects_category` schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pojects_category` (
  `project_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  KEY `category_id` (`category_id`),
  KEY `project_id` (`project_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `pojects_category` (`project_id`, `category_id`) VALUES
(94, 3),
(94, 1);
```

Am I missing something?

**Solution**: use `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT`

Comment: If you only want one of each project, append `GROUP BY project_id` to your query

Comment: Don't use group by, see my explanation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this is fine. This is just one of the rare cases when you want to use the `DISTINCT` key word to remove duplicates.

In this case this is justified by the fact that the logic of the query is correct, even though it returns more than one row. Many times one can see the usage of `DISTINCT` when actually the logic of the query is wrong.

Side-note:

- any filter on a table reference you're using in the `WHERE` clause other than `IS NULL/IS NOT NULL` would make any `LEFT JOIN` on this same table reference turn to an `INNER JOIN`, as for the final resultset behaviour. (see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15483895/1291428)
- you ought not use `GROUP BY` to simulate the effect of `DISTINCT`, for 2 reasons:

  1/ This is just not the purpose. One of the effects of `GROUP BY` is to eliminate duplicates, but its main purpose is to group rows according to a certain set of criteria, in order to apply some analytic calculations/operations on them.

  2/ `GROUP BY` also `ORDER BY` the results (in mysql), which is not necessarly what you want and in that case slows down the execution. Please, just ensure appropriate use of what the engines are providing, that's always better from the point of view of forward compatibility. (anticipating that what you include as granted is actually not)

regards.

Comment: well, i didn't know that..i tought group by was a synonym for DISTINCT. Thanks, now i'm using distinct and it works great :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also rewrite this as an "IN" to get around duplicates:

```
SELECT projects.*
FROM projects      
where projects.id in (select project_id
                      from projects_category
                      WHERE pojects_category.category_id IN (1,3,11)
                     ) and
      projects.id='94'
```

The "in" prevents duplicates from forming when you are using joins for filtering records.