# SQL JOIN USING and WHERE

Tags: sql, join, ansi-sql

This is somewhat of a followon to [SQL JOIN where to place the WHERE condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483808/sql-join-where-to-place-the-where-condition)

I would prefer to use the USING clause on the join, but am not yet able to put the field value condition with the join.

```
SELECT 1
  FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2 USING(id) AND t2.field = 0;

ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Is it possible to have USING and another condition as part of the JOIN clause?

Comment: No it is not possible.

Comment: The accepted answer that you link to is poor. See my comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SELECT 1
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 USING(id)
WHERE t2.field = 0;
```

Using `USING(id)` is like using `ON t1.id = t2.id` except that in the `JOIN` result instead of two columns `t1.id` & `t2.id` there is only one `id` column.

For `INNER JOIN USING` with a condition followed by an `OUTER` `JOIN` you need a subquery to keep the `WHERE` with the `USING`:

```
SELECT ...
FROM (SELECT id, ...
    FROM table1 t1
    JOIN table2 t2 USING(id)
    WHERE t2.field = 0) s
LEFT JOIN ...;
```

For an `OUTER` `JOIN USING` with a condition you need a subselect:

```
SELECT ...
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
    FROM table2 t2
    WHERE t2.field = 0) t2
USING (id);
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25957600/3404097) re `ON`/`WHERE` with `JOIN`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31014799/3404097) re `ON`/`WHERE` when mixing `INNER` & `OUTER` `JOIN`s.