# How to rewrite a statement, that uses the MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY to a standard SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, group-by, having-clause, sql-mode

It ueses the [`MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) and cannot be executed, if the `sql_mode` is set to `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.

```
-- SET sql_mode = ""; -- reset sql_mode and execute statement
SELECT
    `courses`.`id` AS `id`,
    `courses`.`title` AS `title`,
    `courses`.`description` AS `description`,
    MATCH (coursedata.title) AGAINST ('Salsa') * 5 + MATCH (coursedata.description) AGAINST ('Salsa') * 2 AS `relevance`
FROM `courses`
INNER JOIN `coursedata` ON `courses`.`id` = `coursedata`.`id`
GROUP BY `courses`.`id`
HAVING `relevance` >= '3'
```

Is it possible to reach the same effect with standard SQL?

Comment: Why are you grouping by in the first place? You're not using agregation functions. your having clause should be a WHERE clause and the group by could be removed.

Comment: It's non-standard SQL so there is no standard for it ;) You can get close by adding everything to your `GROUP BY` or adding `MAX()` everywhere.

Comment: @Sebas You're right, here `GROUP BY` doesn't really make sense. But it's just the "core" a longer SQL statement, where I have to `GROUP BY` in irder for filter duplicates out.

Comment: DISTINCT filters, group by groups, that's different! See my answer there if you wish to know more: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11416345/1291428

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work...

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        DISTINCT `courses`.`id` AS `id`,
        `courses`.`title` AS `title`,
        `courses`.`description` AS `description`,
        MATCH (coursedata.title) AGAINST ('Salsa') * 5 + MATCH (coursedata.description) AGAINST ('Salsa') * 2 AS `relevance`
    FROM `courses`
    INNER JOIN `coursedata` ON `courses`.`id` = `coursedata`.`id`
) AS subselect
WHERE `relevance` >= '3'
```

Comment: here you go! What about passing the where inside the subquery? It would be more logically correct I guess.

Comment: I's not possible: `Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'relevance' in 'where clause'` That was, why I was using `HAVING`.

Comment: I see. Using alias within where clause is forbidden probably. Would have to rewrite the whole match line then...