# COUNT output rows in a joined query in SQL

Tags: mysql, join, count

i've two table :

```
programmes[id,name,..]
notes[id,note,id_prgm,..]
```

I actually have a request to know some info about prgm and associated notes :

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, ...
FROM programmes p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN notes n
    ON (n.id_prgm=p.id AND ...)
WHERE ...
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY ...
LIMIT 20
```

And it work great, but now I want to know how many row this query can give to me (without the LIMIT)
So I try to put a COUNT(p.id), but it give me the number of note for each programme. And not the full number of programmes.

So who can i edit this query to know that ?

(mysql with php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, ...
FROM programmes p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN notes n
    ON (n.id_prgm=p.id AND ...)
WHERE ...
GROUP BY p.id WITH ROLLUP
```

You will have the count per program and then a NULL, TOTAL COUNT row after that.
Also, take care of the following:

> When you use ROLLUP, you cannot also use an ORDER BY clause to sort
>   the results. In other words, ROLLUP and ORDER BY are mutually
>   exclusive. However, you still have some control over sort order. GROUP
>   BY in MySQL sorts results, and you can use explicit ASC and DESC
>   keywords with columns named in the GROUP BY list to specify sort order
>   for individual columns. (The higher-level summary rows added by ROLLUP
>   still appear after the rows from which they are calculated, regardless
>   of the sort order.)

If you want the total count shown in each row, remove the group by:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, COUNT(*)
FROM programmes p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN notes n
    ON (n.id_prgm=p.id AND ...)
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ...
```

If you want the count to appear for each record but keeping the group by, do the following:

```
SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT p.id, p.name, ...
    FROM programmes p
        LEFT OUTER JOIN notes n
        ON (n.id_prgm=p.id AND ...)
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY ...
    ORDER BY ...
) t
```

The limit clause is not supported within a subquery though, you'll have to find something else.

---

I think you want to DISTINCT, not GROUP BY. This is not the same thing and should not be mixed up. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11416345/1291428) to this question for further informations.

Comment: The "WITH ROLLUP" is what a looked for, thanks ! Just another question about that : can i have the null row in first ?

Comment: Hum, I speak too fast, when I use ORDER BY and this solution, I've an error :  Incorrect usage of CUBE/ROLLUP and ORDER BY

Comment: Let me see if there's a problem with the 2 things

Comment: See my side note: add `ASC` or `DESC` to the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: It's not possible in my case (I need to use calculated value to sort my rows and it seem not possible). But I will try others solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a query that counts the rows of your query (which will be a subquery):

```
select count(*)
from (select p.id, ... from ... )
```

Of course you can skip the aggregate functions and the group by to make the subquery faster, just add `distinct` in your subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select distinct p.id, ... from ... )
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

with `php` and `mysql` you can use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` while using `limit` in query you just need to run the `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` just after your query executes will returns all no of rows found

```
$query = 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  p.id, p.name, ...
FROM programmes p
LEFT OUTER JOIN notes n
ON (n.id_prgm=p.id AND ...)
WHERE ...
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY ...
LIMIT 20';
mysql_query($query);
$query = 'SELECT FOUND_ROWS()';
mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have PHP count the rows for you.

Here's how I do it:

```
$sql = "<your-query>";
$resource = mysql_query($sql);

if (! $resource = mysql_query($sql) ){
    echo "Error reading from table $table";
    die;
}

if (! $num = mysql_num_rows($resource ) ){
    echo "No records found in $table";
}
else {
    echo "$num rows found";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource)){
        //...
        // other stuff you want to do
    }
}
```

Note: I use `mysql_` functions, but there should be a similar way in `mysqli_`.