# Use DISTINCT with two columns (or something that works)

Tags: sql, distinct

I got a table with Cities and States it looks something like:

```
cityid    |city    |stateid    |state
--------------------------------------
0566      |abriaqui|05         |antioquia
0599      |alejand |05         |antioquia
0511      |another |05         |antioquia
0782      |dummy1  |09         |caldas
0783      |dummy2  |09         |caldas
0785      |dummy3  |09         |caldas
0788      |dummy4  |03         |Narino
0767      |dummy5  |03         |Narino
0734      |dummy6  |03         |Narino
```

As you can see I have Cities with uniques IDs, and the state they belong to is just to the right, with the state id and the state name. I would like to make a query that returns something similar to DINSTINCT(state):

```
STATE
--------------------
antioquia
caldas
narino
```

But I need the stateid too. How can I reach this?

Comment: which engine + give a proper expected resulset. Rigorous questions give rigorous results, and the contrary too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT state, stateid
FROM table
```

Comment: I feel bad now that I see it was that easy... I mean, I was trying to use DISTINCT (sate, stateid) with PARENTESIS... May be that's why it wouldn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: @JuanBonnett don't worry just try reading the documentation for whatever DBMS you're using next time you have a doubt or are unsure of the syntax, believe me it helps a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
select distinct state, stateid
from tab
```

you can also use `group by` clause

```
select state, stateid
from tab
group by state, stateid
```

Group by is useful if you need some aggregation function. 
Solution is depend of your requirements.

Comment: Do not use group by instead of distinct: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11416345/1291428

Comment: @Sebas Yes I know, I added information when group by is usfel

Comment: I was using SELECT DISTINCT(sate, stateid) .... that's why it wouldnt work, because of the ()

Comment: @JuanBonnett Yes It doesn't work with `()`, Don't forget to accept a chosen answer to avoid low accepted rate an close the question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
select distinct stateid, state
from CityStates cs
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Distinct stateid, state  
from myTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You should rearrange your database to store states in separate table STATES(id, name) and CITIES(id, name, state_id), then for selecting states you can use

```
SELECT id, name from STATES
```